# Images in div tab switcher not all floating left on firefox

Tags: html, css

Click on the tabs and see what happens to the images, they aren't all floating left of one and other. Stripping down page code to the bare code needed to reproduce the issue results in more than one image being in the wrong location rather than just one but don't think it matters in the end.

I need the images in each tab to float left and not be all over the place.
There's quite a lot of code involved in the switcher.

So far it seems like firefox is the only one not cooperating and im yet to test chrome desktop and safari.

Working/not

Mobile browsers

Firefox/ no
Opera/ yes
Opera Mini/ yes
Chrome/ yes
Default galaxy browser/ yes

Desktop browsers

Firefox/ no
Opera/ yes
IE/ yes

Tia

Live example
http://www.techagesite.com/aadockissue.htm

```
.clear{
clear: both;
}

.tabs__item2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;

}


@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .tabs--lg {
    border: 1px solid #0A3D5D;

  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__content {
    border-width: 0;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-color: #0A3D5D;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list {
    background: #0A3D5D;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list .tabs__item {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list .tabs__item--active {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list--open .tabs__item {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__list--open .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: none;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-right: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link {
    background-color: #0A3D5D;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  .tabs--lg .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: .5em solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #0A3D5D;
    float: right;
    margin-top: .75em;

  }
}

@media (max-width: 1070px) {
  .tabs--xl {
    border: 1px solid #0A3D5D;

  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__content {
    border-width: 0;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-color: #0A3D5D;

  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list {
    background-color: #0A3D5D;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list .tabs__item {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list .tabs__item--active {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list--open .tabs__item {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__list--open .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: none;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-right: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link {
    background-color: #0A3D5D;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  .tabs--xl .tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: .5em solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #0A3D5D;
    float: right;
    margin-top: .75em;

  }
}

.tabs__list {

margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;

background: #0A3D5D;

display: flex; /* Added */
}

/*
.tabs__list {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}*/


.tabs__item {
padding-left:1px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}

/*
.tabs__item {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}*/

.tabs__item--active > .tabs__link {
  border: 1px solid #0A3D5D;

  background: #0A3D5D;
  border-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  color: #333333;

}
.tabs__item--active > .tabs__link:hover {
  color: #262626;
}

.tabs__link {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333333;
  padding: .0em 0em;
  line-height: 0;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}
.tabs__link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.tabs__area {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;
          transition: opacity .5s linear;
  height: 0;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}

.tabs__area--active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;
          transition: opacity .5s linear;
  height: auto;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}

.tabs__content {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background: #0A3D5D;
  border: 0px solid #0A3D5D;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding: 0px;
  padding: 0.0rem;

}

  .all {
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 2px solid #006699;
    background-color: #0F3053;
}

#root { max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto; 
background-color:#0F3053;}

#box1 { width: 100%; 
background-color:#0F3053; padding:0px 2px 0px 2px;}
#box2 { width: 50%;     background-image:url('https://freephonewallpapersformobile.files.wordpress.com/2015/11/header-logo1.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position: left;
    -webkit-background-size:contain;
    -moz-background-size:contain;
    -o-background-size:contain;
height:188px;


}

#box3 { width: 50%; 

background-color:#0F3053;


}



#box4 { width: 20%; }
#box5 { width: 60%;

background-color:#0F3053;padding-right:10px; padding-left:10px;}
#box6 { width: 40%; padding-right:10px;
margin: 0 auto; background-color:#0F3053;}
#box7 { width: 100%; }

.border {  
  border: 1px solid #006699;
border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
border-top-right-radius:8px;
border-top-left-radius:8px;
overflow:hidden;}

.container-dock {
  padding: 0rem;

  max-width:700px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #0A3D5D;
}

.cats {
    width: 100%;
  height: auto;}


.c1, .c2, .c3, .c4, .c5
{background-image: url('https://freephonewallpapersformobile.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/dock-cat-sprite1.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;


    -webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    outline:none;


}



.c1 {background-position: 0px 0px;}
.c2 {background-position: 0px -52px;}
.c3 {background-position: 0px -104px;}
.c4 {background-position: 0px -156px;}
.c5 {background-position: 0px -208px;}


.d1, .d2, .d3, .d4, .d5, .d6
{background-image: url('https://freephonewallpapersformobile.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/desktop-sprite2.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:100px;
height:56px;     
     border: 0;
    width:100px;
    height:56px;
    outline:none;
    display:inline-block;

}


.d1 {background-position: 0px 0px;}
.d2 {background-position: 0px -58px;}
.d3 {background-position: 0px -122px;}
.d4 {background-position: 0px -180px;}
.d5 {background-position: 0px -238px;}
.d6 {background-position: 0px -296px;}


.m1, .m2, .m3, .m4, .m5, .m6
{background-image: url('https://freephonewallpapersformobile.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/mobile-sprite11.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
     display:inline-block;
     border: 0;
    width:100px;
    height:56px;
    outline:none;

}


.m1 {background-position: 0px 0px; 
}
.m2 {background-position: 0px -58px; 
}
.m3 {background-position: 0px -116px; 
}
.m4 {background-position: 0px -174px; 
}
.m5 {background-position: 0px -232px; 
}
.m6 {background-position: 0px -290px; 
}
.main {
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;


}
    .top_grow11{

    float: left;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }

    <div class=all>
        <div id='root'>

            <div class='box' id='box2'></div>
            <div class='box' id='box3'>

</div>
                        <div class='box' id='box5'><div class='main'>

          <div class="border">
<div class="container-dock"> 
    <div class="tabs tabs--md">
        <ul class="tabs__list list-unstyled">
            <li class="tabs__item  tabs__item--active">
                                <a href="#tab-1" class="tabs__link">
                <img class="c1"></a> </li>
            <li class="tabs__item">
                <a href="#tab-3" class="tabs__link">
                <img class="c2"></a></li>
            <li class="tabs__item">
                <a href="#tab-2" class="tabs__link"><img class="c3"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="tabs__item">
                <a href="#tab-4" class="tabs__link"><img class="c4"></a></li>
            <li class="tabs__item fill">
                <img class="c5">
            </li>
        </ul><div class="tabs__content">
            <div id="tab-1" class="tabs__area tabs__area--active">

                      <div class="top_grow11">  
            <a href="http://www.techagesite.com/hd-wii-wallpapers-mario-kart-super-mario-galaxy-2.htm">
                <img class="d1"></img>

            </a>
        </div>

          <div class="top_grow11">
            <a href="http://www.techagesite.com/free-music-wallpaper-big-music-wallpapers.htm">
                <img class="d2"></img>

            </a>
        </div>

          <div class="top_grow11">
            <a href="http://www.techagesite.com/awesome-minecraft-hd-desktop-wallpapers-1080p-backgrounds-1920x1080.htm">
                <img class="d3"></img>

            </a>
        </div>

          <div class="top_grow11">
            <a href="scooby-doo-wallpapers-character-backgrounds-coloring-pages-the-gang.htm">
                <img class="d4"></img>

            </a>
        </div>

          <div class="top_grow11">
            <a href="free-hd-neon-colours-desktop-wallpapers-download.htm">
                <img class="d5"></img>

            </a>
        </div>

  <div class="top_grow11">
            <a href="cool-hd-desktop-wallpapers-1920x1080.htm">
                <img class="d6"></img></a></div></div>
            <div id="tab-2" class="tabs__area">
                                  <div class="top_grow11">
            <a href="facebook-timeline-covers-photos-851x315.htm">
                <img class="cats" src="thumbs/fb-cover_small.jpg"></img>                
                </a></div>
            </div>
            <div id="tab-3" class="tabs__area"><div class="top_grow11">

                <a href="hd-minecraft-mobile-phone-wallpapers-1080x1920-steve-creeper.htm">

<img class="m1"></img></a>
        </div>

        <div class="top_grow11">

                <a href="hd-disney-frozen-wallpapers-for-mobile-phones-1080x1920.htm">

<img class="m2"></img></a>
        </div>

        <div class="top_grow11">

                <a href="legend-of-zelda-ocarina-of-time-mobile-phone-wallpapers.htm">

<img class="m3"></img></a>
        </div>

        <div class="top_grow11">

                <a href="hd-super-mario-bros-world-mobile-phone-wallpapers-1080x1920.htm">

<img class="m4"></img></a>
        </div>

        <div class="top_grow11">

                <a href="lg-g2-g3-htc-one-max-s-m8-mobile-phone-wallpapers.htm">

<img class="m5"></img></a>
        </div>

        <div class="top_grow11">

                <a href="android-hd-mobile-phone-wallpapers-1080x1920.htm">

<img class="m6"></img></a></div></div><div id="tab-4" class="tabs__area">
              <div class="top_grow11"><a href="twitter-headers-and-background-covers-1500x500.htm">  
<img class="cats" src="thumbs/caterpillar.png"></a>
            </div></div>
            <div id="tab-5" class="tabs__area">

            </div>            <div id="tab-6" class="tabs__area">            </div></div>
    </div>

</div></div><!----><div class="clear"></div>


</div>  <div class="clear"></div>



        </div></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>










        <script>
var app = {};

app.tabs = (function() {
    var module = {};

    module.init = function() {

        var $tabs            = $('.tabs');
        var $tabList         = $('.tabs__list');
        var $tabItem         = $('.tabs__item');
        var $tabItemActive   = $('.tabs__item--active');
        var $tabLink         = $('.tabs__link');

        var width            = $(window).width();

        var tabSwitcher = function() {
            // On tab link click
            $tabLink.on('click', function(e) {
                var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

                // Show/Hide Tabs
                $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).addClass('tabs__area--active').siblings().removeClass('tabs__area--active')

                // Change/remove current tab to active
                $(this).parent('li').addClass('tabs__item--active').siblings().removeClass('tabs__item--active');

                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }

        var tabToggle = function() {
            $tabItem.on('click', function(e) {
                $(this).parent($tabList).toggleClass('tabs__list--open');
            });
        }

        var tabController = function() {
            tabToggle();
        }


        $(window).resize(function() {
            var width = $(window).width();
            if ($(window).width() != width) {
                width = $(window).width();
                tabController();
            }
        });

        tabController();
        tabSwitcher();

    };
    return module;
})();

app.tabs.init();
```

Comment: Page wasn't on server but now is.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `display: inline;` to `.tabs__area--active`

and apply `display: none;` to `.tabs__area`

Comment: @Techagesite I just upload a picture. You want to float the buttons to the left. Am I right?

Comment: @Techagesite Do you mean the images under the tabs??? Apply `display: inline;` to `.tabs__area--active` and apply `display: none;` to `.tabs__area`